# Leftbar Hamburguer Menu Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my application, the left bar hides when you open the page in a mobile resolution, but I can't do the "hamburguer button" work.

Every solution that i find, did not work.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#leftSidebar">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left row ">

                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar opficio dashMenuFont sidebar-offcanvas" id="leftSidebar" role="navigation">
                            <div class="nav-img">
                                <img src="img/userDefaultImage.png">
                                <p class="opficio-bold userName"><?php echo strtoupper($_SESSION ['nickUser']) ?></p>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dash-menu">
                                <ul class="nav">
                                    <li><a href="dashboard.php?p=home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Início</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="dashboard.php?p=search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Buscar</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="dashboard.php?p=watched"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span> Assistido</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Bate-papo</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Config.</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="nav-logo-bot">
                                <img src="img/nav-logo.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                        <?php
                        $link = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'p');
                        include $link . ".php";
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As it is, the left bar hide and the hamburger button show, but the button didn't work and a top bar stay in the top of my page, when i removed it, the hamburguer button had disapears

Thanks.

@edit
how the application is:
[Tela web desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GRoF.png)

[tela web mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLuyh.png)

Comment: Could you create a fiddle so we can see the issue in action?

Comment: Bootstrap needs javascript functionality to make the button work. Have you imported the necessary libraries as shown here: [link](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js) ?

Comment: @reveN
I had imported using local files, and now I've tried with your link and it almost works ... but now I can at least try

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this 
`<nav class="navbar navbar-default"> </nav>`  in your code

check it here
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp